# Max and Min have the same variance

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d uniform variables between 0 and 1. Define

$Min_n = \min(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$

$Max_n = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$

How can we show that the variance of $Min_n$ and $Max_n$ are the same? What is the intuition behind it?

Thank you.

Comment: This can't be true in general. What is the distribution of the $X_i$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. There were typos in the original question. I've edited it. $X_i$s are uniformly distributed i.i.d. between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

The intuition is simply that when $X_i\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim }U(0,1)$, then by symmetry,

$$1-\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$$ has the same distribution as $$\min\{X_1,...,X_n\},$$

so $\text{Var}(\min\{X_1,...,X_n\})=\text{Var}(1-\max\{X_1,...,X_n\})=\text{Var}(\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}).$

If you want to more explicitly convince yourself that the above objects have the same distribution (i.e. same CDF), look into some prelims of [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). To obtain the CDFs, it may help to recognize

$$\{X_1,...,X_n:\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}\leq x\}\quad = \quad \bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_1,...,X_n: X_i\leq x\}\\
\{X_1,...,X_n:\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}\geq x\}\quad=\quad \bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_1,...,X_n: X_i\geq x\}.$$